# Correlated Query? Update query to make dynamic with dates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

I initially wrote a with statement to gather my list of client ID's that were contacted by rep on a certain date.

I realize that the query is not dynamic the way it is written. I eventually want to query multiple reps within a date range rather than just one date.

I need the query to look forward 90 days based on the date of the initial call and tell me if a certain action was taken (i.e. purchase)

I think I have to write a correlated query but not sure how to go about it. TIA.

```
With CSA_CONTACT AS (SELECT part_id 
FROM table 
WHERE REP_ID = '12345' 
AND CALL_DATE = '03-Dec-2020'),
PURCHASE AS (SELECT PART_ID, PURCHASE 
FROM PUR_TABLE 
WHERE PUR_DATE BETWEEN '03-Dec-2020 AND dateadd(DAY, 90, '03-Dec-2020'))
SELECT C.PART_ID
CASE WHEN P.PURCHASE is not null then 'Y' ELSE 'N' END PURCHASE_IND
FROM CSA_CONTACT C LEFT JOIN PUR_TABLE P WHERE C.PART_ID = P.PART_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for `group by` solution as follows:

```
Select t.rep_id, t.part_id,
       Case when dateadd(DAY, 90, min(t.call_date)) > min(p.pur_date)
            then 'Y' 
            else 'N'
       end as purchase_ind
  From table t
  Left join pur_table p on p.part_id = t.part_id
 Where t.rep_id in (multiple reps like - 123,456, ...)
 Group by t.rep_id, t.part_id
```